# Python: iterating with .items() or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code

```
for endpoint in endpoints:
    if key in endpoints[endpoint]['keys']:
        yield endpoint
```

`pylint` suggests iterating it with `.items()`

```
for parent,child in endpoints.items():
    if key in child['keys']:
        yield child
```

Now when I do, I get a warning about an unused variable called `parent`

Which is the better approach for maintainability and/or performance?

Comment: Those two generators don't yield the same values. The first yields the keys of the outermost dict. The second one yields the dicts which are values of the outer dict. Which one do you want?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't require the parent as per your second example, I'd suggest you use:

```py
for child in endpoints.values():
    if key in child['keys']:
        yield child
```